# how to combine multiple column of different table into one table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables a, b and c and need to arrange these table data as target table and all of these tables (a, b, c) are not in database they are fetched from from single table using queries as alias and need to arrange these tables into target table using query. How to do that

```
   table a     |      table b     |   table c     
               |                  |               
  id | a_vals  |     id | b_vals  |  id | c_vals  
  ------------ | --------------   | ------------- 
  1  |  123    |     1  |  123    |  1  |  123    
  2  |  124    |     2  |  142    |  2  |  142    
  3  |  234    |     4  |  234    |  5  |  234
```

target table

```
id | a_val| b_val| c_val
1  | 123  | 123  | 123
2  | 124  | 142  | 142
3  | 234  |  -   |  -
4  |  -   | 234  |  -
5  |  -   |      | 234
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: This is ugly, because you're going to need two full outer joins.  A well designed database would also have another table containing all IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a, b and c share the same name for the column you want to join, you could use "USING" to avoid duplicate keys in the resulting table:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b USING (id)
  FULL OUTER JOIN c USING (id);
```

Alternativly, since a, b and c's value column all have distinct names you could use NATURAL JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN b
NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN c;
```

Be careful not to accidentally rename any of the other columns tho, since natural join removes any duplicate columns.
You can also omit the "OUTER" keyword if you like, but i would leave it for clarity, (since LEFT, RIGHT, and FULL imply an outer join).
See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-table-expressions.html for details

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
 select aa.id, a_val, b_val, c_val from 
 (select distinct id as id from table_a
 union
 select distinct id as id from table_b
 union
 select distinct id as id from table_c)aa
 left join (select id, a_val from table_a)bb on aa.id = bb.id
 left join (select id, b_val from table_b)cc on aa.id = cc.id
 left join (select id, c_val from table_c)dd on aa.id = dd.id order by aa.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN t1.id IS not null THEN t1.id
    WHEN t2.id IS not null THEN t2.id  
    ELSE t3.id
  END 
  AS id,
t1.a_vals AS a_val, 
t2.b_vals as b_val, 
t3.c_vals as c_val
FROM a t1  FULL OUTER JOIN b t2 ON t1.id=t2.id FULL OUTER JOIN c t3 ON 
CASE
    WHEN t1.id IS not null THEN t1.id
    ELSE t2.id
  END = t3.id
```

OR

```
SELECT  COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id, t3.id) as id ,
            t1.a_vals AS a_val, 
            t2.b_vals as b_val, 
            t3.c_vals as c_val
    FROM a t1 FULL OUTER JOIN b t2 ON t1.id=t2.id 
    FULL OUTER JOIN c t3 ON COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) = t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the ANSI-standard `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id, c.id) as id, a.val, b.val, c.val
from a full join
     b
     on a.id = b.id full join
     c
     on c.id = coalesce(a.id, b.id);
```

You can also implement this with `union all`/`group by`:

```
select id, max(a_val) as a_val, max(b_val) as b_val, max(c_val) as c_val
from ((select id, val as a_val, null as b_val, null as c_val
       from a
      ) union all
      (select id, null as a_val, val as b_val, null as c_val
       from b
      ) union all
      (select id, null as a_val, null as b_val, val as c_val
       from c
      )
     ) abc
group by id;
```

Comment: on a.id = b.id this only work if both table have same ids

Comment: full join give all the column of both the table if ids match

Comment: @NawazSharif . . . Are you trying to say the code doesn't work?  Have you tried it?

Comment: "You are looking for the ANSI-standard" - you appear to be referring to SQL-92, which is an ISO.IEC standard. Also note the OP is in India. What distinction are you trying to make by referring to a non-specific American standard?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better done in the 'front end' e.g. this is the kind of thing a reporting tool is designed for.

Avoiding nulls and outer joins (because they by definition produce nulls):

```
SELECT a_val, b_val, c_val
  FROM a 
       NATURAL JOIN b 
       NATURAL JOIN c
UNION
SELECT a_val, '-' AS  b_val, '-' AS c_val
  FROM a 
 WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM b )
       AND id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM c )
UNION
SELECT '-' AS a_val, b_val, '-' AS c_val
  FROM b
 WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM a )
       AND id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM c )
UNION
SELECT '-' AS a_val, '-' AS  b_val, c_val
  FROM c
 WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM a )
       AND id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM b );
```